# how to identify data is displaying or not in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

condition:how To check data is displayed or not

```
Boolean isPresent3 = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".input-horizon.horizon-program-guide.form-control.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid.ng-not-empty.ng-valid-min")).size()> 0;

if (isPresent3 == true) {
    System.out.println("Aflam data exists");                    
}
else {
    System.out.println("Aflam data does not exists");
}
```

[image]

```
Boolean isPresent3 = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("csspath")).size()> 0;
```

this code some time works sometimes not any good solution that works evrytime

Comment: use isdispalyed method of selenium to check whether element is displayed or not.

Comment: @PoojaPathange Which `data` is constantly displayed within the page? Update the question with text based relevant _HTML_

Comment: And note that it's better to just say `if (isPresent3)`--don't compare booleans.

Comment: @GautamBothra boolean check2 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("csspath")).isDisplayed();  if im using this code for more than 3 times its not working , ihave created different methods and applied above code still its not working

Comment: Does more than 3 times means 3 different executions or 3 different test data, could you pls elaborate & share relevant html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check whether the element is visible use isDisplayed() method which returns boolean values (ie)

```
List<WebElement> element=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".input-horizon.horizon-program-guide.form-control.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid.ng-not-empty.ng-valid-min"));    
 System.out.Println(element.size());   
 if(element.isDisplayed()==true){
 System.out.Println("element is present");
 }
 else
 {
 System.out.Println("element is not present");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It checks whether the element is present on the page. To check visibility of the element you should use "isDisplayed()". My suggestion is to use both the conditions.

```
List<WebElement> elem= driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".input-horizon.horizon-program-guide.form-control.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid.ng-not-empty.ng-valid-min"));
if(elem.size()> 0){
    if(elem.get(0).isDisplayed()){
        System.out.println("Element is dislayed and present");
    }
}
else{
    System.out.println("Element is not present");
}
```

Comment: i m constantly getting this error when im applying this logic for more than 3 time ,it is trying to find xpath fallowing error exception is - no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".input-horizon.horizon-program-guide.form-control.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid.ng-not-empty.ng-valid-min"}
  (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.99)

Comment: List<WebElement> elem= driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".input-horizon.horizon-program-guide.form-control.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid.ng-not-empty.ng-valid-min"));      it try to find this css path

Comment: Can you share the HTML of your page so that I can try at my end?

Comment: i dnt have html page can you able to see my attached file above (1)in drop down we have list of tv channels by selecting one by one channel (2)click on submit data will come (3) if no data only blank screen will come

Comment: I am making one update in my answer. Now It will check the visibility of the element only if the element is present on the page else "Element is not present" will be displayed and I can't validate your CSS selector unless you provide me with the HTML source.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it works sometime and not all the time then it may be the case where the element takes time to be available in dom and your `findElements` statement executed before it's available!

- Quick and dirty work-around is, add sleep, for example `Thread.sleep(3000)`.
- Anther work-around is you can have waitForElementpresent condition in try catch block and in catch block you can set flag false!

If you are using [qaf](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/) you can use [assertion/verification](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/assertion_verification.html) available with driver and element object where you don't need to use any of above work-arounds. For example in your case it may look like:

```
$("css=csspath").verifyPresent(); // checks only presence in dom. 
$("css=csspath").verifyVisible();// ensures present and displayed
```